# LEFT OUTER JOIN

Tags: mysql, join

Buenas tengo una duda con el LEFT JOIN, tengo las tablas GÉNEROS Y PELÍCULAS, y necesito sacar los géneros de los cuales no tengo películas almacenadas, todo esto sin utilizar mi atributo derivado numpeliculas

[image: Esta es la estructura de las dos tablas]

esta es la consulta (ya se que esta mal) pero llevo muchos intentos y no consigo dar con el funcionamiento.

```
SELECT NGCGENEROS.nombre, NGCPELICULAS.genero
FROM NGCGENEROS
right OUTER JOIN NGCPELICULAS ON NGCGENEROS.nombre = NGCPELICULAS.genero
GROUP BY NGCGENEROS.nombre;
```

Basicamente necesito que me muestre lo que me muestra esta consulta 
SELECT NGCGENEROS.nombre, NGCGENEROS.numpelicula
FROM NGCGENEROS
WHERE NGCGENEROS.numpelicula = 0;
CON LEFT JOIN y sin utilizar el atributo derivado GENEROS.numpelicu

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y cual seria el problema?

Comment: Ya he recurrido a google y he estado probando durante varias horas y no consigo sacarla la consulta, por eso acudo aquí. Y sigo sin conseguir sacar los géneros de los cuales no tengo películas almacenadas sin acudir a mi atributo derivado

Comment: Añade la estructura de tus tablas así como la consulta que has tratado y será más simple ayudarte

Comment: se relacionan en la tabla de peliculas  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
 nombre VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
 duracion INT NOT NULL,
 estreno INT NOT NULL,
 director INT NOT NULL,
 genero INT NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT FK1_PELICULAS_DIRECTORES FOREIGN KEY(director) REFERENCES NGCDIRECTORES(id)
 ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT FK2_PELICULAS_GENEROS FOREIGN KEY(genero) REFERENCES NGCGENEROS(id)
 ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
)ENGINE=INNODB CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci';

Comment: @element no veo porque tiene que usar claves foraneas, ni donde seria conveniente dicho paso.

Comment: no puedo usar el atributo derivado GENEROS.numpelicula, con el atributo lo saco sin problema pero sin el y utilizando el JOIN no lo consigo

Comment: se me pide que lo haga con un join, pero si no es mucho pedir y me lo explicas de las dos maneras te lo agradecería, y yo aprendería algo que no se

Comment: Usando subconsultas `SELECT COUNT(NGCGENEROS.nombre) FROM NGCGENEROS WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT * FROM NGCPELICULAS WHERE NGCPELICULAS.genero = NGCGENEROS.nombre )'

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, con el count también la he conseguido sacar pero también me prohíben su uso en esta consulta

Comment: Pues usa `LEFT JOIN`y `HAVING`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok. Se me ocurren dos formas de hacer esto:

En uno de los casos, solo tenes que hacer lo siguiente, traer toda la tabla izquierda, pero solamente para los casos donde la tabla derecha tenga un campo nulo

```
Select generos.nombre
from NGCGENEROS generos
left join NGCPELICULAS pelis ON generos.id = pelis.genero
where pelis.genero = null
```

Y la otra forma, como bien lo describieron en los comentarios, es buscar en la tabla generos, solo aquellos que no existan en la tabla peliculas, pero contando por afuera los casos.

```
select generos.nombre
from NGCGENEROS generos
where generos.id not exists(select genero from NGCPELICULAS)
```

Comment: vale, creo que mas o menos he pillado como funciona, voy a probar a ver, muchas gracias por toda la ayuda :)

Comment: Recuerda hacer el [tour], mirar [ask] y tambien aceptar una respuesta cuando te sirva. Suerte! @JuniorGarcia

Answer (score 1):

¿Que tal esta?

```
SELECT g.* 
  FROM NGCGENEROS AS g
  LEFT JOIN NGCPELICULAS AS p ON p.genero = g.id
 GROUP BY g.nombre
HAVING COUNT(p.id) = 0
```

Unimos con `LEFT JOIN`  y con `HAVING` restringimos las válidas sólo a aquellas con suma cero, es decir, sin películas.

Comment: muchas gracias por la ayuda voy a probar esta también junto con el ejemplo de gbianchi, ha ver que tal. muchas gracias :)

Comment: Esta query anda, pero solo en mysql cuando no se pone el modo estricto. En cualquier otra base de datos, esto no funcionaria.

Comment: en principio es solo para mysql, muchas gracias por la ayuda